# Why did Bella choose Edward over Jacob?

Tags: movie, twilight

In the movie series *Twilight*, why does Bella choose Edward over Jacob? What is it about Edward that made Bella so attracted towards him? What was wrong with Jacob? Why a Vampire over a Werewolf?

Comment: Because if she'd chosen Jacob the story wouldn't have as many parts in the series - fewer challenges and story bumps and an earlier resolution.

Comment: also: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FirstGirlWins

Comment: Why all the downvotes? As the answer clearly indicates, it's NOT a dumb nor unanswerable question, despite seeming simplicity

Comment: The only reason Jacob liked Bella is because of the child she is going to have.

Comment: Based on the existing answers, there seem to be a *range* of good reasons why he likes her (and vice versa).

Comment: It's all right, Jacob, you don't have to hide behind anonymous “user221287” names. We won't judge you.

Comment: I can't believe nobody said "because she had carpeting in her house and didn't want to have to deal with the shedding" :)

Comment: I have no idea why anyone would go for cold blooded creatures. I mean, when you can't feel the heat of your partner in the bed, what's the point?

Comment: @Bat I understand that Edward sparkles.  Bella could save a **fortune** on replacement nightlights, and disco balls.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This question goes to the very heart of the relationships between Bella and the two men. The best explanation from the books comes from chapter 26 of Eclipse (and explains the title of the book - other than the title, it's the only other use of that word). (Jacob and Bella are talking)

> Two futures, two soul mates ... too much for any one person. And so unfair
>   that I wouldn't be the only one to pay for it. Jacob's pain seemed too
>   high a price. Cringing at the thought of that price, I wondered if I 
>   would have wavered, if I hadn't lost Edward once. If I didn't know what
>   it was like to live without him. I wasn't sure. That knowledge was so deep
>   a part of my, I couldn't imagine how I would feel without it.
>
> "He's like a drug for you, Bella." His voice was still gentle, not at
>   all critical. "I see that you can't live without him now. It's too late.
>   But I would have been healthier for you. Not a drug; I would have been the
>   air, the sun."
>
> The corner of my mouth turned up in a wistful half-smile. "I used to think
>   of you that way, you know. Like the sun. My personal sun. You balanced out
>   the clouds nicely for me."
>
> He sighed. "The clouds I can handle. But I can't fight with an eclipse."

Answer (score 3):

Every one seems to miss the point that Edward is a genetically perfect predator - OF HUMANS. He is designed to be OVERWHELMINGLY attractive to his prey through physical beauty, pheromones, mannerisms etc. When Edward turned his attention to Bella she never had a choice. There was no exercise of free will. She did NOT fall in love, she became addicted, obsessed. Her reaction to his departure in New Moon was a pretty good description of withdrawal from drugs.
This should give  an indication of just how strong her feelings for Jacob grew, that
she developed them even in the crucible of her obsessive feelings for Edward. If Edward had stayed away a bit longer allowing Bella to finish healing and a bit more time for the relationship with Jacob to grow, I think Bella would have easily chosen Jacob.

Comment: This seems, to put it mildly, unsupported. Is there any evidence that vampires have "pheromones" to control humans? Does this account for Bella's continued attraction to Edward after she became a vampire?

Answer (score 3):

Bella loved  both men in different  ways.

Her love for  Edward  was based  off physical attraction, an unhealthy  obsession,  and  a desire  to be young and  beautiful  forever.  She was always  worried  he was going  to  leave  her and  she  never  felt good  enough  for  him. He controlled  her life and  made the decisions  for them. He was older  than  her (90 years older) and he knows  all the ways to manipulate her and  get  away  with  it. He's  jealous  and  possessive but Bella didn't  mind. He was her first  love...

Her love  for  Jacob was based  off more of a mental  connection. They  shared the same  heart  and  with him she could  be herself  with  out  worrying  about  judgment.  He was her sun. The only  person  who  could  heal her  broken  heart  and  make  her laugh. He
Bella often  worried  he was too good  a person  for  her. He was temperamental  but Bella  never  had  a problem  telling  him how she felt.  He was younger  than  Bella so he was a little  immature  and  he sometimes  made stupid  decisions but Bella always  made  sure  he apologized  and she  forgave  him.

With Jacob  she would  have  lived  a full  life in the sun, had children,  went  to  college,  and  grown into  her full potential.

With Edward,  she will live forever,  never  changing,  never  growing, she'll  raise her daughter  who  will always  be with  them and  never  leave,  she'll  never  go to  college and  out live all  her human  friends  and  family.

I think  she chose  Edward  over  Jacob Because  in the end  she was addicted  to Edward. She also  wanted  what  he could  offer  her. Bella  had low self-esteem  and never  felt  pretty  enough,  or young  enough.  She  always  felt out of place and  Edward  offered  a solution.  If she chose  him she could  become  a vampire which  would guarantee her eternal  youth and  beauty. Also,  she  was lonely  and  Edward  offered  her a family  that  would  never  leave  her. Jacob  could  offer  her life  but he couldn't  offer  her youth  or beauty.  He could  offer  her family  but  there was no guarantee  the pack would  stay  together  forever.  After all they  would  eventually stop phasing and  start  having  families  of there own  separate  from  the pack. Bella  would  have  went  to  college and  Jacob  would  have  joined  her in a year but there was never  a guarantee  that  they  would  last a year  of separation.  Then there was the fear  that  he would  one day  imprint though  if Bella  never  had  a baby  with  Edward  then  Jacob  would  have  been  Bella's mate for  a long  time.  But i guess  she needed certainty and  stability something  Jacob  couldn't  offer her...yet. Edward  was her moon and  Jacob  was her sun. But she would  rather  spend  an  eternity  in the dark as long as she was guaranteed some one  to be there  with  her than  stand  and burn in the sun uncertain  whether her  happiness  would  last  or if she'd  have  to walk  alone.

Comment: You've laid out the reasons she was attracted to each, but why did she choose one over the other?

Comment: Good point about how this choice is about security versus true growth and development.

Comment: @Null because she's addicted. Why else does anyone choose heroin over *anything*?

Answer (score 3):

With Jacob, Bella would have never been like him. Bella could never turn into a werewolf but with Edward, she could be like him. Also, she was more close to Edward than Jacob and had the same Similarities. In the second book, edward leaves Bella because he thinks that if they were together Bella wouldn't be able to live a normal life anymore, therefore, he leaves her because he loves her. Jacob, however, dosesn't think that his life might impact her's if they were to be together. That means that Jacob doesn't love her enough to leave her for her own safety. Yes, Edward broke her but he did it for her own safety and health, he did it because he thought that her life would be more normal and safe if he wasn't with her. That doesn't mean that Edward doesn't love Bella. Also in the fourth movie after Bella gets better and sees her daughter for the first time she figures out that Jacob has imprinted on her daughter. After she questions why Jacob replies " You know how much you wanted me three days ago right? It's gone now." 
Bella: "long gone"
Jacob: " It was her It was nesse"
That proves that Jacob's love for Bella was never love. If he had loved her he would have left her, but he stayed for her daughter. So for all the Jacob and Bella fans are you trying to say that Jacob should date his future mother in law ar should Bella love a guy that doesn't love her?

Answer (score 2):

Bella simply loved Edward more. She had feelings for Jacob but even when Edward wasn't there and Jacob and her had the tightest connection they had had (the middle of The New Moon) Bella still tried to see Edward through reckless behaviour. When Leron was about to kill her Bella chose her last words to be 'Edward I love you' not 'Jake I love you'. I think Edward and her are soul mates with an indestructible connection and the fact that he will do anything for her happiness makes him even more attractive for her. In Eclipse Jake asks Edward 'What if she chose me? Would you kill me?' Edward says 'However tempting that thought could be....no' he wished for Bella's happiness whereas Jake continued to try to get Bella to admit her feelings for him which is in my view selfish. Edward loved Bella more than Jake did and Bella loved Edward more than she loved Jake.

Answer (score 1):

Bella was infatuated with both of the men, which made it hard for her to decide who she craved to be with. If she had chosen Jacob, she would have had a normal human life. However, with Edward she would have had a new lust of life, a vampire life which would make her feel more alive. On the first 3 movies, the colours are quite bland and lifeless, but in the last 2 movies, the colour brightens up, signifying that she feels more alive with Edward than with Jacob. It might have seemed sad for Jacob, but deep down he knew that he could never give Bella what she really wanted, and that was to feel alive. Thank You for reading!

Answer (score 1):

From the first movie,

> Edward: I am a killer.
>   Bella: I don't believe that.
>   Edward: That's because you believe a lie. **It's camouflage... I'm the world's most dangerous predator. Everything about me invites you in, my voice, my face, even my smell.** As if I would need any of that... As if you could outrun me... As if you could fight me off... I'm designed to kill.
>   Bella: I don't care.

And, in the second movie, Bella gave answer to your question to Jacob: "Edward is my first love."

Answer (score 0):

The reason why Bella chose Edward over Jacob was because he was her first love. He became a drug to her and she couldn't live without him e.g. in 'New Moon.' I don't agree that Bella and Edward are closer than Bella and Jacob because I think Bella talks to Edward more and they do make jokes about stuff e.g when Edward told her about how Charlie was feeling.You guys might not think like that because of his old fashioned tone and his over protectiveness.  Jacob is close with Bella. They do talk like friends but I think they should just be best friends.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Bella chose Edward over Jacob because he was simply the best option, his family loved Bella, not to mention Edward's deep infatuation with Bella, and although Jacob offered her a pack and a somewhat normal life, I don't think she would be happy, mainly because she still loved Edward.

No matter how great of a time she had with Jacob, she will always love Edward more because he gave her an option, if she wanted to be with him or she did not, whereas Jacob did not give Bella much of a choice, he made sure that she payed attention to no one else other than him and he was extremely jealous when Bella was with Edward. Therefore, Edward was the best option for Bella because even though she could have lived her life to its potential with Jacob, perhaps she did with Edward.

She loved Edward and her child more than anything else in the world, and who knows, if she had a child with Jacob and she almost died, like with Edward's child, who would have been there to save her, to bite her, to capture her beauty and Heath in one frame. But most of all, who would have been there to save her life. Her child would constantly live in vain, due to the fact that him/her would had never had the chance to meet her/his mother.

Edward was the best option for Bella for many more reasons than Jacob.

Answer (score 0):

Bella chose Edward over Jacob simply because she loved Edward more. Edward always tried to have Bella's best interests in mind and whenever he was angry with her (rarely), it was because one or both of them wasn’t being careful with Bella's fragile, human body. Many people say that Bella was addicted to Edward like he was a drug, which may be true because love and attention are things craved by nearly every human. True love drives people a little bit crazy. Beauty attracts the eyes, but love attracts the heart. Yes, Bella was originally attracted to Edward’s beauty, but she fell in love with him. Love is only truly felt through the heart. Yes, Bella and Jacob loved each other, but it was more of a sibling or best friend love, than that of lovers. 
   Bella loved Edward because he was talented, beautiful, and cared about her in a way that no one else did. Edward loved Bella because she was down to earth, compassionate, brave, and didn’t realize how amazing she really was. Bella wanted to be a vampire because she wanted to be with Edward forever. She was afraid that if she grew old, Edward would leave her because, like most teens, she was self conscious about her appearance. However, she was also excited about the perks(beauty, grace,etc)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6zCw.gif)

Comment: Also, Bella didn't want him for immortality, but if immortality was the way for her to stay with him forever, that's whst she wanted. She also wanted to be beautiful so that it would make sense to her as to why Edward loved her.

Comment: I choose neither, thank you! :P

Answer (score 0):

I feel Bella liked Edward more not because she was addicted to him like a drug or felt he controlled her. I feel it had to do more with her feeling a sense of overall attractiveness toward Edward just like the waiter did in the diner. If anyone felt like they were addicted to someone like a drug then it has to be Edward who said

> Her blood was like his own personal brand of heroin.

By the way if Jacob wasn't her type it wasn't because he imprinted on Bella's baby because he loved her way before the baby appeared or was in Bella's stomach. He liked her and so did Edward for one reason and one reason only.                    That reason was she wasn't like other girls in the face of all she saw she stayed and stuck through it all when many would of fled.

Has the thought she liked Jacob maybe for a second she thought God he's hot and I'm cold you could keep me safe and warm. Then just maybe these darn vampires wouldn't want to kill me.

However, since the moment she saw Edward sparkle and said what he was a "Vampire" she knew she liked him more then he even realized. Until one biology class later sitting side by side. So to all that believe in love at first sight that is just what Bella believed in when she saw Edward and his siblings walk in to that cafeteria that first day of school.

For wanting to be a Vampire is purely only because she doesn't have to die before him or without him. Just like the quote

> If I live to know you and love you and you live a hundred days I hope to live one day less so I'm never without you.

Comment: But why did she not choose Jacob? What was wrong with Jacob?

Answer (score -1):

I'd say that Edward was more of drug to her. A girl looks for someone who is a younger version of her father or paternal figures. Everything she gave up when living with Renee resurfaced as soon as she met Jake and the pack. Aside from that. Would any parent just accept the return of the emotional abusive boyfriend after he turned her into a vegetable emotionally.

If id been Bella, once I connected to Jake and his pack, I'd look to the future, live up to my true potential and accept what he had to offer, I wouldn't hold on to the past. And not when the man who has hurt me this much emotionally asks for a second chance and he gets innocent bystanders, including a man who was probably a paternal friend, or more to me, killed.

Yes she loves Jake, but Jake is everything a father is looking for in a future suitor. Jake is a healthier choice, a much healthier choice.

Comment: Answers are better if they explain that they are based on the book/movie, rather than being personal opinion.

Answer (score -1):

I think Bella just became addicted to Edward and because of that she did not love Jake back. In my point of view I think that's a bit selfish because Jake loved her with all of his heart and she just killed his feelings. Jake loved her for who she is and who she will be where as Edward just wanted her and she wanted Edward because he offered her immortality.

Comment: While you are entitled to your opinion, can you explain why we should consider this to be the correct answer?